# How do I impose condition on Diagonal elements of a Matrix in R Language

Tags: r, matrix

I am working in R language. I want to impose condition that if any of the upper diagonal element of a matrix is greater than 0.5 then it prints it in output.

I am using the following code but it prints other than diagonal elements which are not required.

```
for(i in 1:ncol(X))

for (j in i+1:ncol(X)-i){
if(mat(X)[i,j]>0.5)

#upper.tri(cor(X),diag=F)

cat(i,",",j," th element", " > 50%","\n")
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please provide reproducible example. what is `mat` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`which()` should be able to work for you here, using the `arr.ind` argument to return the matrix indices. You can use `upper.tri` as you thought, and an additional logical selection criterion ( > 0.5) to find those elements that fit your description:

```
set.seed(3234)
m <- matrix(runif(16),nrow=4)

m
#          [,1]       [,2]      [,3]       [,4]
#[1,] 0.24903346 0.06965592 0.8715103 0.92297359
#[2,] 0.81593852 0.99991663 0.3717652 0.67191551
#[3,] 0.85413490 0.13877853 0.7990082 0.04143296
#[4,] 0.01439058 0.27303603 0.5246000 0.08486883

which(m > 0.5 & upper.tri(m) , arr.ind = TRUE )
#    row col
#[1,]   1   3
#[2,]   1   4
#[3,]   2   4
```

Note, that this doesn't include the diagonal by default, if you want to include the diagonal, use the `diag=TRUE` argument like this `which(m > 0.5 & upper.tri(m , diag = TRUE) , arr.ind = TRUE )`

Comment: @imdadullah you are welcome! I wouls suggest that as you seem to be new here that you have a quick glance over the [**About**](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and [**FAQ**](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) sections of the website to help you get the most out of SO. Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 5):

1) Note that `i+1:ncol(X)-i` equals `1:ncol(X)` regardless of `i` (as the two instances of `i` cancel) which is not likely what you intended.

2) Also note that this can be done without a loop:

```
# create test matrix
set.seed(123)
m <- matrix(runif(25), 5)

# ix selects large elements
ix <- m > .5 & upper.tri(m)
s <- sprintf("\nm[%d, %d] = %f > 0.5", row(m)[ix], col(m)[ix], m[ix])
```

which displays as follows:

```
> cat(s, "\n")

m[1, 3] = 0.956833 > 0.5 
m[1, 4] = 0.899825 > 0.5 
m[1, 5] = 0.889539 > 0.5 
m[2, 5] = 0.692803 > 0.5 
m[3, 5] = 0.640507 > 0.5 
m[4, 5] = 0.994270 > 0.5
```

The matrix `m` used above is:

```
> m
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]       [,4]      [,5]
[1,] 0.2875775 0.0455565 0.9568333 0.89982497 0.8895393
[2,] 0.7883051 0.5281055 0.4533342 0.24608773 0.6928034
[3,] 0.4089769 0.8924190 0.6775706 0.04205953 0.6405068
[4,] 0.8830174 0.5514350 0.5726334 0.32792072 0.9942698
[5,] 0.9404673 0.4566147 0.1029247 0.95450365 0.6557058
```

Comment: I left the formatting and printing details to the OP. +1 for a fully worked solution.

Comment: An alternative to printing the output would be to display `ix*m` .  I have an easier time visualizing the location of the desired values that way (I know that's not what the OP asked for).

Comment: @Carl, or perhaps: `print(ifelse(ix, "*", " "), quote = FALSE)`